# How Stackoverflow jump to the exact location of the comment or reply?

Tags: asp.net, scroll, maintainscrollpositionon

I am developing a forum site for my company's internal use.
I am developing it using asp.net.

So when a user started a thread other users can reply to it. So then I show a notification on the top to thread owner by using signalR.

So in Stackoverflow when I click on a notification if it is a reply then SO directly go to that thread. ( This is doable. I am generating hyperlinks in the notification messages and its already working. ) But how then SO jump to the exact location of the comment or a reply and then highlight it? If there are pagination in the page how this is possible?

Comment: How your pagination is working? Are the pages created by ASP.NET-Code or are you using some JavaScript-Pagination?
To link a special post on the site is easy (keyword: html anchor), but if your pages are created by your Code, you must handle the paremeter with postId in the controller-method, which is showing the target thread

Comment: @NPC I am handling it by the code. by using pagination by datalists.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign "#" to threads/posts and add them into the link. eg: reply #1200 at thread "HELP" the link will be yourdomain.com/forum/Help#1200.